# Can I use .NET 6.0 abstractions in a .NET Standard 2 library for use in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's say I have a library that adds a middleware to an ASP.NET Core 3.1 pipeline.

```cs
// in library code
// dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions --version 3.1.22
public class MyStartupFilter : IStartupFilter
{
    public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
    {
        return builder =>
        {
            builder.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
            next(builder);
        };
    }
}

// in netcoreapp3.1 code
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IStartupFilter, MyStartupFilter>();
    }
}
```

The library references `IStartupFilter` from the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/3.1.22 package.

Now comes the time to add .NET 6 support to my library so I figured I should update my library to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/6.0.0.

```sh
# in library code
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions --version 6.0.0
```

Will `MyStartupFilter` still work in the .NET Core 3.1 app after this update? Conversely, if I don't update the abstractions, can I use `MyStartupFilter` in a .NET 6 app? Or is the answer neither and do I need to add multiple target frameworks to my library?

The abstractions packages target `netstandard2.0` but I feel like that's not accounting for the ASP.NET Core version.

Comment: You're confusing the version of Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions with the version  of .NET that it can run on. Click on the "Dependencies" tab on the Nuget pages. Versions 3.1.22 and 6.0.0 will both run on .NET Standard 2.0+, so both versions will run on both .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 6. Version 6.0.0 actually supports the older .NET Framework 4.6.1 in addition.

Comment: Isn't it true that the abstractions are versioned the same way as ASP.NET Core? I know for sure that my netcoreapp3.1 uses v3.1.x of the generic host. It seems unlikely that I can use a library that impements the v6.0.0 version of the abstractions in older ASP.NET Core versions?